# Translate a g++ command for terminal compilation to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I am a beginner in CMake and I am trying to follow a tutorial for a project I am currently working on. The tutorial can be found here: https://gepettoweb.laas.fr/doc/stack-of-tasks/pinocchio/master/doxygen-html/index.html#OverviewInstall (Part: More complex example with C++ and Python).
At some point, this tutorial provides a g++ command for compilation, but because of the specifities of my project, I can't use the terminal and have to translate this command to a CMakeLists.txt. Here is the command:

```
g++ -I /path/to/eigen -I /path/to/pinocchio/include/ -DPINOCCHIO_URDFDOM_TYPEDEF_SHARED_PTR -DPINOCCHIO_WITH_URDFDOM overview-urdf.cpp -lboost_system -lurdfdom_model -o overview-urdf
```

My problem concerns the second part of the command, starting from the flags. I added my executable and the two first path, and then I wrote this:

```
target_compile_definitions(overview-urdf PUBLIC PINOCCHIO_URDFDOM_TYPEDEF_SHARED_PTR PINOCCHIO_WITH_URDFDOM)
target_link_libraries(overview-urdf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so)
target_link_libraries(overview-urdf /opt/ros/foxy/lib/liburdfdom_world.so)
```

But if I try to build everything, the compilation fails and indicates an error in a file from the Pinocchio library I use (a file that I did not modify and on which there is no git issue declared). The functions in which a problem is indicated seem to all be concerned by the PINOCCHIO_URDF_SHARED_PTR, thus I expect that there is a problem with how I inserted the flags in my CMakeLists.

I hope that it is clear enough. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: extract of the error message

```
In file included from /opt/openrobots/include/pinocchio/parsers/urdf.hpp:261:0,
                 from testPinocchio.cpp:1:
/opt/openrobots/include/pinocchio/parsers/urdf/geometry.hxx:256:7: error: template-id ‘getLinkGeometry<urdf::Collision>’ for ‘urdf::CollisionConstSharedPtr pinocchio::urdf::details::getLinkGeometry(urdf::LinkConstSharedPtr)’ does not match any template declaration
       getLinkGeometry< ::urdf::Collision>(const ::urdf::LinkConstSharedPtr link)
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/openrobots/include/pinocchio/parsers/urdf/geometry.hxx:252:7: note: candidate is: template<class T> boost::shared_ptr<const T> pinocchio::urdf::details::getLinkGeometry(urdf::LinkConstSharedPtr)
       getLinkGeometry(const ::urdf::LinkConstSharedPtr link);
```

And here is the corresponding code extract; coming from the corresponding file on the git of Pinocchio:

```
template<typename T>
      inline PINOCCHIO_URDF_SHARED_PTR(const T)
      getLinkGeometry(const ::urdf::LinkConstSharedPtr link);

      template<>
      inline ::urdf::CollisionConstSharedPtr
      getLinkGeometry< ::urdf::Collision>(const ::urdf::LinkConstSharedPtr link)
      {
        return link->collision;
      }

      template<>
      inline ::urdf::VisualConstSharedPtr
      getLinkGeometry< ::urdf::Visual>(const ::urdf::LinkConstSharedPtr link)
      {
        return link->visual;
      }
```

Comment: If you use `make` for build the project, you may run it as `make VERBOSE=1` and see **exact command lines** used for build the project. Thus you may check whether option `-DPINOCCHIO_URDFDOM_TYPEDEF_SHARED_PTR` is passed to the compiler or not.

Comment: Thank you for this tips! Unfortunately I think that I can't use it in my case, as everything is done through Docker and a ROS repo.

Comment: `extract of the error message` - This is a different question with unrelated error message. Create a new question about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
add_executable(overview-urdf overview-urdf.cpp)
target_include_directories(overview-urdf PUBLIC
   /path/to/eigen
   /path/to/pinocchio/include/
)
target_compile_definitions(overview-urdf PUBLIC 
   PINOCCHIO_URDFDOM_TYPEDEF_SHARED_PTR
   PINOCCHIO_WITH_URDFDOM
)
target_link_libraries(overview-urdf PUBLIC 
      boost_system
      urdfdom_model
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it leads to the same error... But I investigated a little bit more, I will edit my post. I keep your syntax nonetheless, far better than mine haha

Answer (score 0):

After trying the syntax proposed by KamilCuk, I got the same error. I managed to use the given g++ compilation command "artificially" in my architecture, and it led to the same error than before... Thus, I think that the error does not come from the CMakeLists itself.

Comment: It would be easier to give you advise if you added the exact error message you are getting to your post.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. As I was sure that the problem was coming from the CMakeLists, I wanted to avoid this as it is very long and completely related to a file of the Pinocchio library. But I will post an extract of the message.